# NVD3 Set Expanded as default

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

In NVD3 you can have charts such as the one at : http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html

The default view when you open it up is 'Stacked'. Is it possible to have the default view set as 'Expanded'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the [latest version of **NVD3**](https://raw2.github.com/novus/nvd3/master/nv.d3.js) try using `chart.style('expand');` to set **Expanded** as you default view.

Here is the full list of options available - **'stack', 'stream', 'stream-center', 'expand', 'stack_percent'**

[Source for the list.](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedArea.js#L329) *I have only tested 'expand' for now, so I am hoping the rest would also work as it should :)*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are there any docs on this or did you find it from the source? It works great thank you very much

Comment: From the source, there isn't any docs for NVD3 yet, as far as I know. Once you get the hang of how NVD3, it gets easy to look at the source.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm digging in now, but getting `chart.style` and chart.offset` are not functions errors

Comment: @shabeer90 hi would you mind taking a look here? I'm having the same problem as Akshat, however the answer you posted did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873250/how-to-force-nvd3-chart-timespan-to-auto-expand