# How to force the nvd3 chart timespan to stretch the width of the chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

http://plnkr.co/edit/ymrqIOGTBqF6TVMTvC4T?p=preview

I have the latest d3 and nvd3 libraries in the plnkr above. When you first view the chart, you will notice that all the timespan ticks `09:00`, `08:30`, `08:00` etc are all squished/overlaid on top of each other on the left xAxis.

Now the timespans will not correctly stretch the length of the chart until the user either clicks on the time range finder below the chart, or resizes the window.

**Currently the chart looks like this on first load:**

[image]

**When it should looks like this:**

[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I found this question here [NVD3 Set Expanded as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039390/nvd3-set-expanded-as-default) however the answer did not work for me.

---

**My nv.addGraph code**

```
var data =[{
    "key" : "Price",
    "color" : "#4C73FF",
    "values" : [ [ 1443621600000 , 71.89],
                 [ 1443619800000 , 75.51],
                 [ 1443618000000 , 68.49],
                 [ 1443616200000 , 62.72],
                 [ 1443612600000 , 70.39],
                 [ 1443610800000 , 59.77]]
}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
          .margin({top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 40})
          .x(function(d,i) { return i })
          .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
          .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

      chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
          var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
          // return time in hours:
          return d3.time.format('%I:%M')(new Date(dx))
      });

      chart.y1Axis
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

      chart.y2Axis
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });

      chart.bars.forceY([0]);
      chart.lines.interactive(false);
      chart.height(300);
      chart.noData("There is no Data to display at the moment.");

      // Remove legend:
      chart.showLegend(false);

      d3.select('#chart svg')
          .datum(data)
          .transition().duration(500)
          .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out!

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(res)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

chart.update();  // <- Needed to add this

// nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

The following line was completely useless:
`nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);`

I moved the chart.update out of that and apparently this is what was needed to trigger the timespan to stretch out.

Comment: The line `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);` is not completely useless, you will need it if you need your charts to respond for window resize.

Comment: Ah true @shabeer90 I guess I was just so frustrated hehe... also building just a mobile app so it doesn't need the `windowResize` however when I go back to our desktop dashboard and use this chart, I'll defs keep that line in.